# Regex Javascript match twitter username with some additional info

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the below test string

```
zoo @foo [bar, baz, boo]  moo @too [bee, zee].
```

I would like to extract JSON

```
{
    foo: [bar, baz, boo],
    too: [bee, zee]
}
```

But I am struggling with the regex in Javascript.

Either I am able to fully match the string within the sq. brackets or first and last. Can someone help out?

Comment: Why don't you post the RegEx that you have so far and state what you actually want the RegEx to do.

Comment: Sounds like you need a combination of regular expressions and some application code. I don't believe a regular expression alone will work right all the time.

Comment: https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299-why-can-t-i-register-certain-usernames --- valid strings (letters A-Z, numbers 0-9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/@(\w+)\s+(\[[^\]+])/g
```

which will match the `@<word>`, a space, and then anything within brackets.  If you're more picky about what's in the brackets, you can replace the `[^\]]` with something like `[,\s\w]`.  Run `.exec` on it in a loop until you get a null result:

```
var res;
while( res = regex.exec( str ) ){
    // res[1] == name
    // res[2] == brackets
}
```

You can generate whatever JSON you want from that, or use it as is.

Comment: There is a problem with the regex `/@(\w+)\s+(\[[^\]+])/g` : ending square bracket is missing. This regex will have only [ and one character after it.

`1/@(\w+)\s+(\[[^\]]+])/g`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var regex = /@(\w+)\s+(\[[^\]]+\])/,
    orig = "zoo @foo [bar, baz, boo]  moo @too [bee, zee]",
    curString = orig,
    match,
    result = {},
    index;
while(match = curString.match(regex)) {
   result[match[1]] = match[2];
   index = curString.indexOf(match[2])
   curString = curString.substring(index + match[2].length);       
}
```

The assumption I have taken is that string can have multiple @foo tags, no normal regex can extract multiple matches. You need to iterate the string until no more matches are found

If you need it in the string format, you can use

```
JSON.stringify(res);
```

Comment: I'd suggest just moving the match into the while statement: `while( c=a.exec( regex ) )`.  And you don't need the `.substr` stuff (it's `substr`, btw, not `substring`) if you use `.exec` instead of `.match`.  And use better variable names than `a` and `c` :)

Comment: Yes, I agree. But your solution using the exec is the best approach. I always tend to forget about exec that it updates its lastIndex (when used regex has a **g** flag) for successive matches.

Comment: Just a pure regex seems impossible without recursion.